# How to use hadoop for continue input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a case that I use Hadoop to listen/receive message from JMS queue. If the queue have the message then trigger map/reduce program, so we don't want the map reduce die we need loop execute map/reduce code many many times.

My problem is:

1. `public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException`   Using this method we return the key and value every times. If I return false the map reduce code will run to finished. If I return true the map/ reduce code will wait for the next key value rather than to call reduce method. so is there any way to run reduce method after map method soon and the nextKeyValue return true to wait the JMS queue next message?.
2. Or anybody has good ideas for Hadoop read continue datasource then to do map/reduce in parallel, the same function with Hstreaming?

Comment: One does not simply use Hadoop for continuous input :)

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: Hmm.., so how should implement my case? do you have any idea for this. i only want to use JMS queue to trriger Mapreduce and make sure the mapreduce can use continues input.